# Ruby how to decrease number of validation checks?

Tags: ruby, validation

I want to refactor validation checks on `Date` fields

```
include Virtus.model

attribute :created_from, Date
attribute :created_to, Date
attribute :updated_from, Date
attribute :updated_to, Date

validate :validate_created_from_is_a_date, if: :created_from
validate :validate_created_to_is_a_date, if: :created_to
validate :validate_updated_from_is_a_date, if: :updated_from
validate :validate_updated_to_is_a_date, if: :updated_to

def validate_created_from_is_a_date
  errors.add(:created_from, "not a date") unless created_from.is_a?(Date)
end

def validate_created_to_is_a_date
  errors.add(:created_to, "not a date") unless created_to.is_a?(Date)
end

def validate_updated_from_is_a_date
  errors.add(:updated_from, "not a date") unless updated_from.is_a?(Date)
end

def validate_updated_to_is_a_date
  errors.add(:updated_to, "not a date") unless updated_to.is_a?(Date)
end
```

as you can see I have 4 attributes which i need to validate for `Date` I've tried the following, but it's not working as it checks for all cases

```
validate :validate_date_attributes, if: :any_date_attributes_defined?

def any_date_attributes_defined?
  created_from || created_to || updated_from || updated_to
end

def validate_date_attributes
  %w(created_from created_to updated_from updated_to).each do |attribute|
      errors.add(attribute.to_sym, "not a date") unless attribute.to_sym.is_a?(Date)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found a good way to handle such cases, hope it would be useful for others:

```
validate :created_from, date_attribute: true, if: :created_from
validate :created_to, date_attribute: true, if: :created_to
validate :updated_from, date_attribute: true, if: :updated_from
validate :updated_to, date_attribute: true, if: :updated_to
```

which will look for `DateAttributeValidator` here it's

```
class DateAttributeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    record.errors[attr_name] << "not a date" unless value.is_a?(Date)
  end
end
```

I really liked it, pretty neat, it's clean and ruby/rails way